# ios - newbie trying to declare a method taking a string parameter and getting syntax error

Tags: ios, ios5

I am trying to declare a function in my .h file that looks like this:

```
-(*NSString) encode: (NSString*) unencodedString;
```

and I get a syntax error:

```
expected a type
```

Here is my .m header for this function:

```
- (NSString*)encode: (NSString*) unencodedString
```

and here is how I am trying to call it:

```
EncodingUtil *encode_object = [[EncodingUtil alloc] init];
NSString *encoded_company_name = [encode_object encode: name];
```

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return type says `(*NSString)`. That's completely backwards. You want `(NSString*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does (and you should really learn C first, you'll get lost in Obj-C if you don't even know how to declare a pointer type!). What you presumably wanted to write is

```
- (NSString *)encode:(NSString *)unencodedString;
```